# If Darth Vader is Luke Skywalker's father, who is Luke's mother?

Tags: star-wars, luke-skywalker

We all know that Darth Vader turned out to be Luke's father, but no mention is made of Luke's mother, or Darth Vader's wife.

Comment: I think it was in the prequels, which you may well have tried to forget. I know I did.

Comment: This is like asking what Darth Vader's original name is.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Padmé Amidala](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Padm%C3%A9_Amidala). Since you know Darth Vader is Luke Skywalker's father you know that Darth Vader is Anakin Skywalker. Anakin (secretly) married Padmé Amidala in *Episode II*:

[image: Anakin and Padme looking at each other during the marriage ceremony overlooking the lake; Anakin wears dark Jedi robes and Padme wears an ornate white wedding gown]

She gave birth to Luke and Leia on [Polis Massa](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Polis_Massa) and gave them their names, as seen in *Episode III*.

[image: Padme giving birth, from the Star Wars Databank article on Princess Leia: Padme lays on the birthing bed with a privacy shield from her waist downwards, Obi-Wan holds one of the babies to her face so she can see it and the medical droid holds the other at her legs]

She died shortly afterwards.

Comment: Since no one else bothered to answer...

Comment: "I volunteer as tribute" --Null, 2016

Comment: I suppose the day may come when this is the top hit on google for "who is Luke's mother."

Comment: That space-modesty thing looks like it doesn't give her much room to move her legs.

Comment: Perhaps it expands.

Comment: In addition to the twins, this picture appears to show a buxom robot nurse and the two people most likely to be both of Luke and his sister's parents.

Comment: @MajorStackings the man in the pic holding one of the twins is Obi-Wan Kenobi, NOT the babies father, Anakin Skywalker (Darth Vader). Obi took Luke to hide him on Tatooine, Bail Organa adopted Leia. Anakin/Vader knew Padme was pregnant (but not with twins) but thought she had died before childbirth. His children were reveiled as alive in Episodes V and VI. He wasn't present at their birth near the end of Episode III.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Maybe. Maybe not. My theory is Obi stabbed his little buddy in the back by cheating with Padme and fathering the twins. The three prequels become watchable from that point of view.  Ani goes off. Obi fails to kill him out of remorse.

Comment: @MajorStackings Padme wasn't the kind of person to sleep around. She was devoted to Anakin, the babies are his.