# How does Padmé's space-modesty thing work?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

Null just posted an [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/132190/if-darth-vader-is-luke-skywalkers-father-who-is-lukes-mother/132191#132191) showing Padmé just after giving birth:

[image: space-modesty thing]

To my untrained eye, it looks too constraining to be able to give birth while under that cover. Does it expand? Was it only placed over her after giving birth?

Is there a canon explanation for how this works? Perhaps the droid delivered the baby and then immediately placed the cover over her.

(Also, what is its real name? I assume they don't call it a "space-modesty thing".)

Comment: The idea of an expanding cover came from [SQB](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/132190/if-darth-vader-is-luke-skywalkers-father-who-is-lukes-mother/132191#comment332406_132191).

Comment: Is it just me, or does it look suspiciously like the thing was added in post-production?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see from timestamp [0:06](https://youtu.be/DeoGfNEGVS0?t=6s) it wasn't on her while she was being scanned, but was over her *while* she was giving birth.

The [official novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novel)) refers to it as a "tent"

> Below the opaque tent that shrouded her from chest down, a pair of
>   surgical droids assisted with her labor. A general medical droid
>   fussed and tinkered among the clutter of scanners and equipment.

This device appears to be the outer space equivalent of medical [drapes](http://www.medline.com/media/catalog/sku/k-c/300x300/K-C89525_HRE01.JPG), providing the patient with some privacy (note that she's in an otherwise exposed room with several people watching) and helping to create a sepsis-free environment.

Comment: She had the "drapes" on when the droid was pulling Leia away from her, though. It looks like Padme had *just* given birth to Leia, which means she would have had it on when she gave birth.

Comment: @Null - Yes. She had it on throughout the birth. Both the film and the novel are in agreement on that.

Comment: I think that the problem is the novelization refers to it being from the chest down but the image clearly shows it being from her waist down... chest down makes much more sense. I don't think it's feasible to give birth in a pencil skirt :D

Comment: @amaranth none of my comments in chat relate to anything canon... only to actual birth practices on Earth. I don't see how this modesty tent could possibly be functional at all.

Comment: @Valorum Right, so unless it expands or something I don't see any way for her to give birth with that thing on (I'm not a nurse or doctor but I've seen a birth).

Comment: @amaranth For all we know, they have a mechanically easier birth process and the babies slide out like greased pigs. :P

Comment: @Catija Actual birth practices could form a good answer. People in the SW galaxy seem to be physiologically the same as real humans, so any evidence you have from how things work with real-life childbirth should still be relevant. Thaddeus does real-world-based answers all the time :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor - In this instance, the real-world answer would be "*floaty robots aren't usually used as obstetricians*".

Comment: @amaranth - The novelisation indicates that it's an opaque tent, which agrees with the film. The fact that it reaches to her chest (as opposed to just above her waist) is technically non-canon, but this seems a very minor point of contention.

Comment: @amaranth - Well, there's the fact that it's surprisingly hard to get the studio (and the actress) to include **graphic frontal nudity** in a film marketed for kids.